# Angular 2 RouteParams breaks my code and Injector doesn't seem to work

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 Beta 5. Everytime I use RouteParams in my child component constructor it breaks my child component like:

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit}  from 'angular2/core';
import {HeroService}   from './hero.service';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {Hero} from './hero';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero',
    inputs: ['id'],
    template: `
  <h2>HEROES</h2>
  <div *ngIf="hero">
    <h3>{{hero.name}}</h3>
  </div>
  `
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    hero: Hero;
    selectedId: number;

    constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams, @Inject(HeroService) private heroService: HeroService) {
        this.selectedId =  +this.routeParams.get('id');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.hero = this.heroService.getHero(this.selectedId);
    }
}
```

I've tried using the following with no success:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector, @Inject(HeroService) private heroService: HeroService) {
    this.selectedId = this.injector.parent.get(RouteParams).get('id');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks my child component".  What happens?  Is an error thrown?

Comment: My child component hero.component doesn't work and the whole component fails to display in the browser although the parent component displays fine. Not even the heading of heor.component displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`, either at bootstrap or in component's decorator:

```
bootstrap(AppCmp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
// or

@Component({
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
  ....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sasxa, I added it on. I think what I am trying to do isn't possible with Angular 2. I resolved the RouteParams problem by removing the

```
<my-hero></my-hero>
```

selector from AppComponent.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

is where the child component is displayed. What I was trying to achieve was to have a list of generated router links in AppComponent relying on the RouteConfig of hero/:id to display the right hero in the child component but [routerLink]="['Hero']" broke the link. I'll leave the code to look at.

**app.html**

```
<div style="width:1000px;margin:auto">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Angular 2 Routing and Navigation</h1>
    <div style="width:200px">
        <div style="text-align:center">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
                        <a [routerLink]="['Hero']">{{hero.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeroService} from './heroes/hero.service';
import {Hero} from './heroes/hero';
import {HeroComponent} from './heroes/hero.component';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html',
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService
    ],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeroComponent]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/hero/:id', name: 'Hero', component: HeroComponent }, ])

export class AppComponent {
    hero: Hero;
    heroes: Array<Hero>;


    constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(HeroService) public heroService: HeroService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
    }

    onselect(hero: Hero) {
        this.router.navigate(['Hero', { id: this.hero.id }]);
    }
}
```